# How to share a file using Microsoft OneDrive Python SDK?

Tags: python, request, onedrive

I'm using [Microsoft OneDrive Python SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) in order to perform some operations in `OneDrive`, like uploading / deleting / renaming a file, creating new folders ... 
However, I have spent a fairly good amount of time trying to read the SDK in order to find out how to share a file or folder, and change / delete / update permissions for such file or folder.

```
self.client = onedrivesdk.get_default_client(client_id=client_id,
                                             scopes=['wl.signin',
                                                     'wl.offline_access',
                                                     'onedrive.readwrite',
                                                     'onedrive.appfolder'])

def copy_item(self, parent_id, item_id, name):
    """
    Make a copy of an existing file

    Args:
        parent_id: (string)
            the file's folder id
        item_id: (string)
            the file id
        name: (string)
            the new name the file
    """
    assert self.client is not None
    try:
        ref = ItemReference()
        ref.id = parent_id
        copy_operation = self.client.item(drive=self.drive, id=item_id).copy(
                        name=name, parent_reference=ref).post()
        copy_operation.poll_until_complete()
    except onedrivesdk.error.OneDriveError, error:
        self.log.exception("An error occurred: {0}".format(error))
```

For example, looking at the [share](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/blob/master/src/python2/request/share_request.py) API, I able to see how the file is shared, but I still don't know how to use the `client` in order to make the request. The documentation isn't very good though. Could someone please help me how can I share / update permissions in a file or folder using the OneDrive Python SDK API?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Python SDK (and the others for that matter) do not yet expose the `permissions` functionality that is exposed [via the API](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/items/permissions.md). It's definitely on the list of changes planned for the SDK, but we cannot comment on timelines etc.

Comment: Brad, not even shared links? If I were to utilize the current API, I would have to do it via Python Requests? Could you please add an example how can I do it so?

Comment: You can create links (view and edit) [using this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/tree/master/examples#get-a-sharing-link), but you won't be able to view the links that exist on the item, delete them, etc as that requires `permissions`